# XML内に記述した色を動的に生成したボタンの背景色にしたい

Tags: wpf

WPFにて動的にボタンを生成する処理を組んでいます。
そのボタンの背景色はXMLで記述した色("Red"など)を設定したいのですが、
XMLに記述した色を背景色に設定する方法がわからず、困っています。
ご存知の方、アドバイスお願い致します。

＜補足＞
XMLに記述した色(文字列)を取得することはできています。
コードビハインドで決めた色を背景色にすることはできるのですが、XMLから取得した色(文字列)を
背景色に設定することができません。

＜ソースコード抜粋＞

```
　　　・
　　　・
　　　・
    System.Windows.Controls.Button but = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
    but.Background = Brushes.Yellow; // XMLから取得した色(文字列)の入れ方がわからず、仮で固定の色を設定しています
    this.Buttons.Children.Add(but);                                                             
　　　・
　　　・
　　　・
```

回答する上で情報に不足あれば、ご指摘いただけると幸いです。

Comment: この記事が該当するのでは？ [Convert string to Brushes/Brush color name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372693/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

コメントで紹介した以下の記事が応用できるでしょう。
[Convert string to Brushes/Brush color name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372693/9014308)

```
string BtnBGColor = "Yellow"; //例えばXMLから取得した色文字列がこんな変数に入るとして

System.Windows.Controls.Button but = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
but.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(BtnBGColor);
this.Buttons.Children.Add(but);
```

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。
上記やり方でやりたいことを実現することができました。